# First strcpy works but second causes segmentation erroy

Tags: c

I am working to implement modifying a struct. For some reason it seems that my first `strcpy()` works, when I comment out the second call to strcpy. However when I try to use both I get a segmentation error. My struct called record looks like this:

```
struct record
{
    char name[25]
    char address[80]
    int yearofbirth
    char telno[15]
    struct record* next
};

 int modifyRecord (struct record *start, char uname[] ,char uaddr[], char utelno[] ) {

    struct record *next;
    next = start;
    while( next != NULL ) {

        if ( strcmp((*next).name, uname) == 0 ){
            strcpy ( (*next).address, uaddr );
            strcpy ( (*next).telno, utelno );
            next = (*next).next;
        }
        else{
            next = (*next).next;
        }

    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A small (and unrelated to your problem) question about style, why do you use e.g. `(*next).name` instead of the more common `next->name`?

Comment: I do have the next pointer set to NULL.

Comment: As for your problem, how do you call the function? What is the values of the strings you pass to the function? How do you create the list?

Answer (score 1):

Plain `strcpy` will copy character by character until it encounters a null character (x'00'). If your string does not end with a null it will continue copying until it either hots a null by accident or reaches the end of the memory you are allowed to address.

Switch to  `strncpy` where you can specify the max length to be copied.

Also are you sure you will actually encounter a "next == NULL" condition.

Comment: Switching to strncpy fixes this problem!